# boost hana: create a map from a set and a default value

Tags: c++, dictionary, boost, set, boost-hana

I have a boost::hana::set of types and want to create a map with it, where the values are bool's.

```
// I have a hana set:
auto my_set = hana::make_set(hana::type_c< int >, hana::type_c< float > ...);

// and want to transform it to a map with a given runtime value as values:
auto wanted_map = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c< int >, false),
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c< float >, false),
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hana::set` is `hana::Foldable` so you can use `hana::unpack`. Consider this example:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;


int main() {
  constexpr auto make_pair_with = hana::curry<2>(hana::flip(hana::make_pair));

  auto result = hana::unpack(
    hana::make_set(hana::type_c< int >, hana::type_c< float >),
    hana::make_map ^hana::on^ make_pair_with(false)
  );

  auto expected = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c< int >, false),
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c< float >, false)
  );

  BOOST_HANA_RUNTIME_ASSERT(result == expected);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jason's answer is perfect, but here's the same thing using a lambda instead (I usually find that more readable):

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
namespace hana = boost::hana;


int main() {
  auto types = hana::make_set(hana::type_c< int >, hana::type_c< float >);
  auto result = hana::unpack(types, [](auto ...t) {
    return hana::make_map(hana::make_pair(t, false)...);
  });

  auto expected = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c< int >, false),
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c< float >, false)
  );

  BOOST_HANA_RUNTIME_ASSERT(result == expected);
}
```